# using getComputedStyle with jsdom

Tags: javascript, jsdom, getcomputedstyle

I fail to get the computed style value of color with jsdom:

```
require("jsdom").env({
    html: '<html><head><style> html { color: red; } </style></head><body></body></html>',
    done: function(errors, window) {

        console.log('color: "'+window.getComputedStyle(window.document.body).color+'"');
    }
});
```

The previous test returns "" instead of "rgb(255, 0, 0)" or "red" ...
(note that this work properly in a browser)

Do I miss something ?

Comment: wrapping `console.log ...` with `setTimeout` ?

Comment: nothing, but maybe there is a trick to trigger the css computation ...

Answer (score 7):

It [seems](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/144df2c727009f264a220a85307ee1b627fc3a9e/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js#L218-L257) like jsdom does not implement inheritance for `getComputedStyle`.

If you get the computed style of the `html` tag it should work however.