# vitest cannot test for presence of specific styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest, tauri

TLDR - None of the methods (console logs or expect) in this test are working - https://github.com/kartik-madhak/noter/blob/help!/recreate-test-issue-branch/src/tests/theme.test.tsx#L20

I am creating a React-Tauri app using Vite. In my application, there is a chakra header being used as a navbar: -

```
 <chakra.header
      data-testid="navbar"
      shadow="sm"
      zIndex="99"
      m="0"
      background={navbarColor}
    >
    ...
```

I am trying to assert that the specific background color is being applied to the header using vitest and RTL: -

```
it('should have a light theme by default', ({ expect, component }) => {
   const navbar = component.getByTestId('navbar')
   const styles = window.getComputedStyle(navbar)
   console.log(
     styles,
     '<<<1',
     styles.background,
     '<<<2',
     styles.getPropertyValue('background'),
     '<<<3'
   )
   expect(navbar.style.background).toBe(allThemes.Lofi.navbarColor)
 })
```

But `navbar.style.background` is empty string. The other console logs (styles.background, styles.getPropertyValue('background')) are also empty strings. What am I doing wrong?
FYI I have tried console logging inside the component and made sure the value is correct there... (The value `navbarColor` in the above component is defined correctly)
Also, I tried inspecting the html in the app, I can see there is a generated class being applied in the header component like this: -
`<header data-testid="navbar" class="css-50pch2">`
Where css-50pch2 is a random class name prob generated by vite or react (idk). Its defined like this: -

```
.css-50pch2 {
    box-shadow: var(--chakra-shadows-sm);
    z-index: 99;
    margin: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)),linear-gradient(179.52deg, rgb(164, 192, 247) 7.08%, rgb(169, 228, 232)34.94%, rgb(176, 226, 184) 65.12%, rgb(207, 223, 162) 96.23%);
}
```

In case you want more info, here is a link to the repo - https://github.com/kartik-madhak/noter/pull/9/commits/a7dacbcd35645b4aea53b78014e5e62ec78b2e7d

Another FYI - Locally, I have already added `css: true` to vite.config.ts like this: -

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import * as path from 'path'

const mobile =
  process.env.TAURI_PLATFORM === 'android' ||
  process.env.TAURI_PLATFORM === 'ios'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(async () => ({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  // Vite options tailored for Tauri development and only applied in `tauri dev` or `tauri build`
  // prevent vite from obscuring rust errors
  clearScreen: false,
  // tauri expects a fixed port, fail if that port is not available
  server: {
    port: 1420,
    strictPort: true,
  },
  // to make use of `TAURI_DEBUG` and other env variables
  // https://tauri.studio/v1/api/config#buildconfig.beforedevcommand
  envPrefix: ['VITE_', 'TAURI_'],
  build: {
    // Tauri supports es2021
    target: process.env.TAURI_PLATFORM == 'windows' ? 'chrome105' : 'safari13',
    // don't minify for debug builds
    minify: !process.env.TAURI_DEBUG ? 'esbuild' : false,
    // produce sourcemaps for debug builds
    sourcemap: !!process.env.TAURI_DEBUG,
  },
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
    css: true,
  },
}))
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69615903/9640177), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29864745/9640177) if you're running your tests in JSDOM (i.e. every Jest test) then CSS isn't fully implemented. Specifically, the cascade part of CSS is not implemented (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/2690). Inheritance is only partially implemented (display and visibility) (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2160).

If you want to test computed styles, you should consider implementing e2e tests. However, you can test for presence of classes on elements and thereby have preliminary confidence in your code.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67515949/9640177) is an example of testing computed styles with `TestCafe`. However, you could also use `selenium` or `cypress`.